# what are the typical reasons a plugin for woocommerce will not work with a wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

i bought a plugin for woocommerce. it doesn't work of course, and the developer simply says "your wordpress theme is the problem, pay me to fix it". i've tested the obvious: do i have `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();` working; do i have any jquery issues (nope), am i using the correct version of jquery (yup), are all files being served from woocommerce into footer or head (yup), do i see obvious jquery or javascript issues when i view in firebug (nope).

so i am somewhat new to woocommerce. new to the point of using a ton of different plugins for functionality that should really be baked in (cough cough). so i am just reaching out to those who have years experience with woocomm and wordpress to see if i can craft a list or ideas that you've known to cause custom wp themes.

i appreciate your time and energy reviewing and offering your help with this.

Comment: There is no standard reason, just conflicting code. Could be anything.

Comment: Any PHP errors? Which plugin?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too vague to provide a proper answer. Try elaborating with information about what plugin you've installed, what theme you're using, what you are trying to achieve, and what result you are seeing compared to the expected result. Does your theme follow guidelines for [WooCommerce Theme Compatibility](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/)? Is your theme overriding a lot of WooCommerce templates? Are these templates up to date? I've seen outdated templates crash sites before so those are worth looking at.

Comment: no php errors whatsoever. plugin is Distance Delivery for WooCommerce

Comment: theme is custom theme i built from scratch. yes it follows the woocommerce theme compability. i only have one custom template that shows all categories, rest use woocomm templates that i over ride the way i should by adding a new folder, etc

Answer (score 2):

Nothing ***should*** be baked into either WordPress or WooCommerce, really. Tens of thousands of programming hours went into those two pieces of software which you are benefiting from, free of charge.

You can read their licence [here](https://wordpress.org/about/gpl/).

However, you should ask for your money back from the plugin developers as they should have clearly stated the conditions for their plugin to work, since it is a premium plugin.

Most certainly, you should not consider paying them for installing the plugin and you should demand firmly that ***it was their responsibility*** to inform you about any limitations their software might have had from performing the tasks they claim it performs.

---

As a side-note, most WooCommerce plugins require your theme to be WooCommerce compatible.

**Edit:** A full list of steps you need to take in order to add WooCommerce compatibility to any theme can be found [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/).

And here are the [WC docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/) on theme compatibility with the plugin.

Comment: i am still trying to figure this out. i would like to ask: if i am able to see products, add to cart, checkout, and pay, and view completed order, then wouldn't my theme be "woocommerce compatible"? every article i see online only says to add support declaration and that's it. pretty useless. i'm beating my head against the wall over here fighting against these paid plugins, where the dev say my theme is the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. WooCommerce works on pretty much any WP installation but that doesn't mean the theme has WooCommerce support. I updated my answer with a link to the steps one needs to take in order to add WC compatibility to a WP theme. From my point of view, it's pretty straight forward but if you have trouble with it I'm willing to help. You can contact me using the website linked in my profile.

Comment: thanks i've sent you an email from your site.